# How to connect to a Tor relay with an exit node

Tags: configuration, exit-relays

A friend of mine installed a Tor relay with an exit node in his server. It has an IP and a port, obviously, but we can't connect (or we don't know) to the node.

We think it has to be done with a proxy, but as I said, we don't know.

Could you help us, please?

Comment: What do you mean, connect to the node? Are you trying to use that as your Exit Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying a particular exit node is not a wise solution, instead it is better to specify a country (better yet, exclude countries you don't want!).

You'll have to edit your `torrc` file: either `ExitNodes` or `ExcludeExitNodes`

Have a look at the [Tor Manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en).

> ExitNodes node,node,…
>
> A list of identity fingerprints, country codes,
>   and address patterns of nodes to use as exit node---that is, a node
>   that delivers traffic for you outside the Tor network. See the
>   ExcludeNodes option for more information on how to specify nodes.
>
> Note that if you list too few nodes here, or if you exclude too many
>   exit nodes with ExcludeExitNodes, you can degrade functionality. For
>   example, if none of the exits you list allows traffic on port 80 or
>   443, you won’t be able to browse the web.
>
> Note also that not every circuit is used to deliver traffic outside of
>   the Tor network. It is normal to see non-exit circuits (such as those
>   used to connect to hidden services, those that do directory fetches,
>   those used for relay reachability self-tests, and so on) that end at a
>   non-exit node. To keep a node from being used entirely, see
>   ExcludeNodes and StrictNodes.
>
> The ExcludeNodes option overrides this option: any node listed in both
>   ExitNodes and ExcludeNodes is treated as excluded.

and:

> ExcludeExitNodes node,node,…
>
> A list of identity fingerprints, country codes, and address patterns
>   of nodes to never use when picking an exit node---that is, a node that
>   delivers traffic for you outside the Tor network. Note that any node
>   listed in ExcludeNodes is automatically considered to be part of this
>   list too. See the ExcludeNodes option for more information on how to
>   specify nodes. See also the caveats on the "ExitNodes" option below.

For example:

```
ExitNodes {us} #use exit nodes in the United States; you can also use IP addresses here, like 15.125.229.117
ExcludeNodes {ru},{ro},{pt},{ph},{pa} #do not use exit nodes from these countries
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Tor Browser Bundle and install it.
2. Go to `..\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor`
3. You will find a file `torrc`. Edit this file with notepad.
4. At the end add `ExitNodes IP`. E.g. `Exitnodes 46.165.223.217`